# How to code a scrapy to grab differently formatted html tables

Tags: python, html, dom, web-scraping, scrapy

I've used scrapy before, but only scraping information from one site. I want to use scrapy to grab information from directories on different sites. On each of these sites the information is stored in a simple html table, with the same titles. How do I calibrate scrapy to grab data from each html table even if the table classes may differ from site to site? On a larger scale, what I'm asking is how to use scrapy when I want to hit different websites that may be formatted differently. I'll include below pictures of the html source and xpaths of several of the sites.

The fields of the table, more or less the same for each site directory[image: 1]]

The xpath for site 1 for the name column[image: 2]]

the xpath for site 2 for the name column[image: 3]]

general html formatting of site 1, with phone number blurred out[image: 4]]

general html formatting of site 2 [image: 5]]

General formatting for a third site, which is different than the first 2 but still in a table with 4 columns[image: 6]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - it's a bit of a pain to have to write a spider for every site, especially if there are 100's and the `Item`s are the same for all of them.

If it fits your need, you might like to store XPaths for each site on a file e.g. a [csv file](https://github.com/scalingexcellence/scrapybook/blob/master/ch05/generic/todo.csv). Then you can fetch URLs and expressions from the csv and use them in your spider (adapted from [here](https://github.com/scalingexcellence/scrapybook/blob/master/ch05/generic/generic/spiders/fromcsv.py)):

```
def start_requests(self):
    with open(getattr(self, "file", "todo.csv"), "rU") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for line in reader:
            request = Request(line.pop('url'))
            request.meta['fields'] = line
            yield request

def parse(self, response):

    xpath = response.meta['fields']['tablexpath']
    ... use xpath it to extract your table
```

If you need to release your spider to e.g. scrapyd or scrapinghub, you will need to package your .csv file along with your code. To do so you will have to edit the `setup.py` that `shub deploy` or `scrapyd-client` generate and add:

```
setup(
...
    package_data={'myproject': ['my_csv.csv']}
)
```

Also in your spider, instead of opening your file directly with `open`, you should use this:

```
from pkg_resources import resource_stream
f = resource_stream('myproject', 'my_csv.csv')
```

Here's an [example](http://www.scrapytutorial.com/2015/12/build-a-news-archive-with-scrapy-and-scrapinghub.html). If you don't deploy your spider, just ignore the above. If you do this will save you a few hours of debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I did that by creating a scrapy project with one spider per site and using the same item class for all the different spiders.